# Error parsing headers: duplicate header 'Content-Type' from DashboardController tunnelAction

Tags: magento-1, development, http-request, response

I'm getting an apache error saying that I have duplicate headers for 'Content-Type'. I see that the `tunnelAction` function correctly adds the header `Content-Type:image/png`, but instead of passing in the parameter to replace the original header, it just appends it to the list. Here is the current code below:

```
$response = $httpClient->setUri(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph::API_URL)
                        ->setParameterGet($params)
                        ->setConfig(array('timeout' => 5))
                        ->request('GET');

                $headers = $response->getHeaders();

                $this->getResponse()
                    ->setHeader('Content-type', $headers['Content-type'])
                    ->setBody($response->getBody());
```

`$headers['Content-type']` is `"image/png"`, but it's not passing in a 3rd boolean parameter to replace the existing header "text/html". I'm wondering if adding my own route to handle this request would be the right fix?

Comment: I've added a answer based on latest Magento, by adding more information about headers and Magento version you could get a better or more specific answer

Answer (score 5):

Yes, adding a rewrite that does pass `true` as the third parameter to the `setHeader()` method would fix this.

Setting the third parameter `$replace` to `true` will make the `setHeader()` method to search the array of headers (already set before) and `unset()` any header with the same name, making the "Content-type" header that you are setting the only one.

By the way, note that the official header name is "Content-Type" with a capital 'T'. The replace function of the `setHeader()` method is case sensitive. So you might still end up with two headers, one "Content-type: ..." and another "Content-Type: ..."

Answer (score 2):

I've looked up. Default Magento will just add one header.
So therefore not giving errors of any kind.

I'm guessing you have a 3rd party module to optimize Magento or serverside Apache/Nginx/PHP setting which also add these headers.

You could look which is set first to make it a little easier to lookup.